# set_include_path function does not work, PHP 5.2.13

Tags: php, roundcube, set-include-path

We are using a VPS server in our company and I'm trying to install Roundcube webmail interface

But I can't even get to the configuration phase because the set_include_path function doesn't work and the script can't find the required configuration files.

I get an error like "Fatal Error, ini_set/set_include_path function does not work."

I assume some php settings is causing this but I don't which one.

I'd be glad if I could get some help.

Thanks in advance

**//EDIT**  Here is the codes from the script

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL&~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

define('INSTALL_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../').'/');
define('RCMAIL_CONFIG_DIR', INSTALL_PATH . 'config');

$include_path  = INSTALL_PATH . 'program/lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR;
$include_path .= INSTALL_PATH . 'program' . PATH_SEPARATOR;
$include_path .= INSTALL_PATH . 'program/include' . PATH_SEPARATOR;
$include_path .= ini_get('include_path');

set_include_path($include_path);

require_once 'utils.php';
require_once 'main.inc';
```

Comment: "Fatal Error, function does not work"? Please post the actual quoted error.

Comment: I get "Fatal error: ini_set/set_include_path does not work." and in the installation folder I get "Warning: require_once(main.inc) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/psa-horde/installer/index.php on line 45"

Comment: See this bug: http://trac.roundcube.net/ticket/1484675

Comment: Thanks but it didn't really help, the link isn't pointing to the related post. And at the bottom of the page it's written that's not a RoundCube bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing this from memory, so it might not be quite right, but I think maybe you are confusing the path and directory separators. There may also be a nicer way to do this than what you are doing (i.e. assembling the whole path at once). Try something like this:

`define('INSTALL_PATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));`

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . INSTALL_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'program' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'lib');
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . INSTALL_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'program' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'include');
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . INSTALL_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'program');

Usually I compress this a little bit with implode, since `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is so verbose:

`...PATH_SEPARATOR . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, Array(INSTALL_PATH, 'program', 'lib'));`

I think by (most importantly) changing some of your PATHs to DIRECTORYs, and (possibly) using incremental `get_include_path` and `set_include_path` calls, it will be more readable, portable and just might work properly.

Comment: you're right I've solved the problem with dirname(__FILE__) function, thanks a lot